# Change limitToLast dynamically

Tags: firebase

I have an app that can load more items when user scrolled at the bottom, I'm thinking one way to handle this is to adjust limitToLast dynamically so the child_added event will get triggered again.

Can I do this without having to rebind my .on() functions?

Comment: Please remember for next time that questions about how a piece of code works, should include the minimal code.

Comment: See [firebase-util's Paginate class](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/toolbox/Paginate/example/), which does exactly this.

Comment: @Kato thanks for the link. It was what I needed.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sorry about that. will be more considerate in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a query like this:

```
var query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(10)
```

And you want to change the number of items shown, you will have to create a new query:

```
var query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25)
```

However: if you're just looking to pick up new items that are added to Firebase, that will happen automatically.

An example may clarify this. Say that you start with a list of 10 items:

```
-Jy39378901
-Jy39378902
-Jy39378903
-Jy39378904
-Jy39378905
-Jy39378906
-Jy39378907
-Jy39378908
-Jy39378909
-Jy39378910
```

With the first query above, you will initially get 10 `child_added` events.

Now if someone later adds an item `-Jy39378911` to this list, you will get two events:

```
child_removed: -Jy39378900
child_added  : -Jy39378910
```

So new items show up automatically. But changing the query parameters is not possible, unless you create a new query.

Comment: I'd add that it's not possible with the default SDK, but certainly with a bit of coding energy. Firebase.util.Scroll accomplishes growing the list in a few lines of code.

Comment: Changing the parameter values of an existing query? Link to the relevant code, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Scroll technically wraps the query in the same API and transparently replaces the Firebase SDK's query internally. I think I linked the example in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doDynamic(offset){
    ref.orderByChild("foo").limitToLast(1 * offset).once('value', function (snap) {
        //do stuff
    })
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.